# How to predict unseen data?

Tags: scikit-learn

Hi I am practicing ML models and facing issue while trying to  predict the unseen data.
The error is coming while doing the onehotencoding for categorical data.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder,OneHotEncoder
labelencoder_x_1 = LabelEncoder() #will encode country
X[:,1] = labelencoder_x_1.fit_transform(X[:,1])

labelencoder_x_2 = LabelEncoder() #will encode Gender
X[:,2] = labelencoder_x_2.fit_transform(X[:,2])
onehotencoder_x = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features=[1])
X= onehotencoder_x.fit_transform(X).toarray()
X = X[:,1:]
```

My X has 11 columns and column 2 and 3 are categorical type(Country and Gender).
Model running fine but while trying to test the model against a random input its failing at onehotencoding.

```
input = [[619], ['France'], ['Male'],   [42],   [2],    [0.0],  [1],    [1],    [1],[101348.88]]

input[1] = labelencoder_x_1.fit_transform(input[1])
input[2] = labelencoder_x_2.fit_transform(input[2])
input= onehotencoder_x.fit_transform(input).toarray()
```

Error:

```
 C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\_encoders.py:451: 
  DeprecationWarning: The 'categorical_features' keyword is deprecated in version 0.20 
and will be removed in 0.22. You can use the ColumnTransformer instead.
  "use the ColumnTransformer instead.", DeprecationWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):

      File "<ipython-input-44-44a43edf17aa>", line 1, in <module>
    input= onehotencoder_x.fit_transform(input).toarray()

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\_encoders.py", line 624, in 
 fit_transform
    self._handle_deprecations(X)

   File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\_encoders.py", line 453, in 
_handle_deprecations
     n_features = X.shape[1]

 AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because you have nested lists.

You should flatten your input list and use that for the prediction.

```
input[1] = labelencoder_x_1.fit_transform(input[1])
input[2] = labelencoder_x_2.fit_transform(input[2])

intput = [item for sublist in input for item in sublist]

input= onehotencoder_x.fit_transform(input).toarray()
```

If you have a nested list, then each element in the list will be considered an item that needs to go through the `fit_transform` function, but since it's a single element, it does not match the shape that fit_transform looks for, which is [1, 10] (1 row, 10 columns).

Comment: While Flattening I am getting AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'

Comment: @ChinmayNayak I have edited my answer. Funny that it didn't work. ***Edit:*** I checked my old code and it seems I was using a Django function. My bad. However, this version of my answer where you iterate through the lists should work for you.

Comment: No ,getting list object error.
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'